# mimic signout with url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

when I do:

```
http://localhost:3000/signout
```

it says:

```
No route matches [GET] "/signout"
```

This is because in my routes config file I have:

```
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

so my question is whether its possible to send a "delete" request via the URL, so instead of pressing a link:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, :method => :delete %>
```

I can mimic the action via URL.

Comment: If you want to be able to just go to /signout you'll need to make that route accessible via get as well as delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.  Although `DELETE` is part of the HTTP spec almost all web browsers only know how to make `GET` and `POST` requestes.  When you click a `link_to` with the `:delete` method Rails actually creates a form on the fly and 'POSTs' it back to the server.  Have a look at [the source code](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js#L164).

Answer (score 0):

If you point your browser to `http://localhost:3000/signout`, that will generate a `GET` request, which doesn't match any routes.

If you click the link generated by `<%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, :method => :delete %>` instead, then you'll get the `DELETE` request as you want. In other words, your code works.

If you're not using other methods on this route, consider refactoring as:

```
delete '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
```

EDIT: Keep in mind that, for Rails, a `DELETE` request is just a `POST` request, with a parameter `_method` set to `'delete'`.

Answer (score -1):

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

make sure to deactivate this in router whic is in last and try once.